# How to use navigation.navigate() in map function

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to display a list of TouchableOpacity to navigate to an other page with navigation.navigate(...).

I'm using map to display the list but I can't navigate, the onPress don't work with this error message : "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

What am I doing wrong ?

```js
function PopupMenuAction ({navigation}) {
   return (
        <>
            <TouchableOpacity style={style.shape1to2} onPress={() => resizeBox(1)}>
                <Text style={style.subtext}>Add <Text style={{ color: layouts.secondary }}>+</Text></Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Modal transparent visible={visible}>
                <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} onTouchStart={() => resizeBox(0)}>
                    <Animated.View 
                    style={[
                        style.popUp,
                            { opacity: scale.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange:[0, 1]}) },
                            { transform: [{ scale }]},
                        ]}
                    >
{/* THERE IS THE CODE WHERE IT DONT WORK 

=>>>*/}

                        {actions.map((op, i) => (
                            <TouchableOpacity style={[
                                style.option,
                                { borderBottomWidth: i === actions.length - 1 ? 0 : 1 }]}
                                key={i}
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CreateReaction')}
                            >
                                <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Title-Font", fontSize: 15 }}>{op.title}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        ))}

                        
                    </Animated.View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe navigation does not exist in your functional components because the error indicates it is undefined.

Try to import the useNavigation() hook from react-navigation library and use the returned navigate function.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function PopupMenuAction ({navigation}) {

   const { navigate } = useNavigation()

   return (
      // rest of your code
   )
```

docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

Comment: its not the issue, navigation components is created in an Navigation.js file with createNativeStackNavigator, then if your screen is in the <NavigationContainer> you don't have to import it

Comment: Ok, so if you are logging the navigation param it isn't undefined? 

Seems like you are trying to use the navigation prop in a component which is not a screen.

Comment: Yea I think so, but its not a screen so how can I navigate to an other screen in a function who is not a screen ?

Comment: See the answer I provided. const { navigate } = useNavigation()